# Sinch ducks webview audio in iOS

Tags: ios, audio, sinch

I am trying to get a Sinch app to app call running in parallel with Youtube video playback.

I have enabled audio mixing using:

```
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:&setCategoryError];
```

but the Youtube audio seems to be ducked to a very low level - you can just about hear it but it's very quiet.

Is the Sinch client using the iOS Voice-Processing I/O Unit AGC? Can this be disabled?

Answer (score 2):

Yes the Sinch SDK is using the Voice-Processing I/O audio unit and it's AGC. It can not be changed or disabled in the current versions (3.X).